# NGINX Rewrite subdomain with multiple . as -

Tags: nginx, rewrite

On my NGINX server, I am rewriting usernames as a subdomain. However, the server that I inherited, the initial names have a "." to separate out two names.

For example: http://foo.com/john.smith is being rewritten as http://john.smith.foo.com.

Due to the wildcard ssl certificate, it's causing havoc displaying images or returning a certificate error due to the multiple "."

How do I rewrite john.smith.foo.com as john-smith.foo.com? Here's the beginning of the subdomain rewrite

```
server {
listen 443 ssl;
server_name ~^(.*)\.<%=rootdomain.replace(".", "\\.")%>$;
set $subdomain  $1;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can construct a server block to match domain names with an embedded `.`.

For example:

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name  "~^(?<prefix>.+)\.(?<suffix>.+)\.example\.com$";
    return 301 $prefix-$suffix.example.com$request_uri;
}
```

But this will still cause trust errors if the wildcard certificate is not valid for the original domain name.